# Powershell "Start-Service" cmdlet not working . Doesn't write anything to the host either

Tags: powershell

I saved this function into StartWindowsService.ps1 file.
I made sure that the executionpolicy is 'Unrestricted'. I ran this file the following way:

Before I ran the next line, I stopped the 'FAService' from services. so that my function will start the service.

I ran the following line at Powershell command prompt. It doesn't write to host anything and doesn't start FASservice. I am really dumb founded.

```
C:\LocationofthisFile\ .\StartWindowsService.ps1 StartWindowsService FAService
```

I also tried

```
 function StartWindowsService{
          Param([string] $ServiceName)
          $aService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
          if ($aService.Status -ne "Running"){
              Start-Service $ServiceName
              Write-Host "Starting " $ServiceName " service" 
              " ---------------------- " 
              " Service is now started"
           }

          if ($aService.Status -eq "running"){ 
                 Write-Host "$ServiceName service is already started"
           }
     }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just a function in a script as you have, when you run the script it will start a new PowerShell scope, define the function because that's all the script does, then quit and clear it up. None of the other things you passed as parameters (function name, service name) go anywhere because the *script* doesn't look for them. Only the function does, and you're not calling the function.

One way forward is to `dot source` the script which is `. .\thing.ps1` with a dot and a space at the start. Or maybe `Import-Module .\thing.ps1`. These will define the function and keep it in your current scope, so you can call it in the shell:

```
c:\path\ > . .\StartWindowsService.ps1
c:\path\ > StartWindowsService FAService
```

Another way forward is to make the script be the function by removing the definition:

```
Param([string] $ServiceName)
$aService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
```

and then you can use it directly from the file

```
c:\path\ > .\StartWindowsService.ps1 FAService
```

and the parameter goes to the `Param()` part of the *script* and it works as if it was a function.